# Programmatically creating a level screen (like Candy Crush)

Tags: swift, cocos2d-iphone, sprite-kit

**QUESTION**

I need to create a progress level map (see below). I have looked at [Sprite Kit](https://dezwitter.wordpress.com/2015/02/23/spritekit-with-swift-introducing-the-level-editor/) and [Cocos2D](http://www.raywenderlich.com/61391/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-3-0-tutorial) but they seem to require that you build the map manually. I would like it programmatically as the number of levels etc. for our game will change with time. Anybody know of a good tutorial/ framework?

**TARGET OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: If all you want is a map for this screen, you can take SOME of the manual process (like repeated code) out of the situation by using a template file. Perhaps a txt file with a grid layout of X and O. X = levelNode & O = space. The candy crush tutorial on RayWenderlich website explains how to create levels using this method, you may be able to use it to also create your level map. When you need to add more levels, just add more X's and O's to your txt file.